# signed division in C

Tags: c, portability, division

I was reading the section on C portability in the book `C Traps and Pitfalls` by Andrew Koening..

On an integer divison

```
q = a/b;
r = a%b;
```

If a is a negative number, apparently the reminder *r* can be a negative or positive number, while satisfying the property

```
q * b + r == a
```

Normally I would expect *r* to be negative if dividend *a* is negative. And that is what I see in a intel machine with gcc. I am just curious have you ever seen a machine that would return a positive reminder when the dividend is a negative number ?

Comment: Because of this problem, The coding standard [MISRA-C](http://www.misra-c.com/Activities/MISRAC/tabid/160/Default.aspx) has a rule (3.3) that states that you must be aware and document how the reminder behaves on a specific implementation. MISRA-C is heavily influenced by Koenig, so if you try to implement all advises in that book, you should consider taking a closer look at MISRA-C.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C99 formalized the remainder as having the same sign as the dividend. Prior to C99 (C89 and K&R), it could have gone either way as both results meet the technical requirements. There are indeed compilers out there non-conforming to the C99 spec in this matter, though I don't know of any off the top of my head.

In particular, section 6.5.5 (Multiplicative operators) states:

> ¶5 The result of the / operator is the quotient from the division of the
>   ﬁrst operand by the second; the result of the % operator is the
>   remainder. In both operations, if the value of the second operand is
>   zero, the behavior is undeﬁned.
>
> ¶6 When integers are divided, the result of the `/` operator is the algebraic quotient with any
>   fractional part discarded.<sup>87)</sup> If the quotient `a/b` is representable, the expression
>   `(a/b)*b + a%b` shall equal `a`.
>
> <sup>87)</sup> This is often called "truncation toward zero".

With this new definition, the remainder is basically defined as what you'd expect it to be mathematically speaking.

EDIT

To address a question in the comments, the C99 spec *also* specifies (footnote 240) that if the remainder is zero, on systems where zero is not signed the sign of r will be the same as that of divisor, x.

> ‘‘When y ≠ 0, the remainder r = x REM y is deﬁned regardless of the
>   rounding mode by the mathematical relation r = x − ny, where n is the
>   integer nearest the exact value of x/y; whenever | n − x/y | = 1/2,
>   then n is even. Thus, the remainder is always exact. **If r = 0, its
>   sign shall be that of x.**’’ This deﬁnition is applicable for all
>   implementations.

Comment: Wow... Yet another thing that simply can not be used in C89.

Comment: @Mahmoud interesting maybe i'm just being picky but  would 0 be considered a negative number  ex : -4%2 :)

Comment: @keety: In an implementation without signed zeros that would always be simply zero, in an implementation with signed zeroes it depends. In C89 it could be +0 or -0, but in C99 only -0. _I think._

Comment: @nightcracker see my revised post.

Comment: @Mahmoud ,@nightcracker thanks, high time i read the standard :)

Comment: Where do you find that footnote 240 in your C99 standard?  In mine, footnote 240 is in §7.19.6.1 (formatted I/O) and doesn't contain that text at all.

Comment: @Mahmoud, Thanks.. but the quote from Section 6.5.5 doesn't say anything about the sign. From this how did you conclude that remainder will be signed when dividend is signed ? May be the C89 had different wordings and your conclusion is based on how it has been changed in C99 ?

Comment: I found the footnote as number 201 in section §7.12.10.2 'The remainder functions' (as part of `<math.h>`).  It applies to the functions such as `double remainder(double x, double y);` rather than to the `/` or `%` operator.  The text says _The remainder functions compute the remainder x REM y required by IEC 60559._ and the footnote 201 appears after the 60559.