# Intel X86: Can idiv yield a negative remainder?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, integer-division

[Idiv](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/IDIV.html) performs signed division as follows:

> numerator:   EDX : EAX
>
> denominator: ECX

And for output,

> quotient: EAX
>
> remainder: EDX

I know EAX -- the quotient -- could be negative. But is it possible for EDX -- the remainder -- to be negative?

Comment: On the X86 the remainder for IDIV is based on signed modulo. If you divide -8 by 5 it should yield a negative quotient (-1) and a negative remainder (-3)

Comment: Yes, `idiv` implements the same signed-division / modulo semantics that ISO C requires.  `idiv` came first;  ISO C89 didn't require that `-5 % 2 == -1`, but allowed it as one of the possible implementation-defined behaviours.  ISO C99 did standardize on the signed division behaviour implemented by x86 and many other ISAs.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023440/signed-division-in-c.  C compilers have been compiling `x % y` to just an `idiv` the whole time, of course.